Как настроен git flow по отношению к различным стендам
Вот для меня как еще не побывашего человека на проекте, до сих пор висит вопрос про стенды и как на них появляется код.Ну как я понимаю стенд грубо говоря это какой-то сервер на котром развернута наша приложуха и она там функционирует.Есть разные стенды, стeнд дев для разработчиков, там разработчики что то пулреквестят, есть стенд тестирования там qa специальисты тестируют продукт, есть стейдж где "зеркало" прода, ну и собсвтенно прод. Для меня непоянтно как код из одого стенда перетекает в другой, не сам процес настройки CI/CD, а как в git-flow это укладывается. Базовый git-flow это dev, main, release и feature ветки. И вот как проходит процес git-flow по отношению к стендами. Разработчик делая пул реквест из feature в dev, код сливается в dev от туда он по идее сразу же деплоится на дев? А после как код оказывается на test стенде? Из каких веток на какие стенды попадет код?

Ну у нас develop ветка - для тест зоны. master и теги - для препрода и прода. Gitlab runner эти разделения умеет определять и выливает в соответствующие контуры. Поищи про конструкцию only в .gitlab-ci.yml.
